# Divide a face into multiple vertical edges

Tags: modeling, edges, faces

Blender newb here. I want to divide a face into multiple faces (vertical edges).

From:

[image: Simple face]

To:
[image: Face divided with multiple edges]

Naturally, I can use the Knife tool and do it manually, but if I have many divisions to create this seems highly inefficient.

For the picture I subdivided and simply deleted each horizontal edge between the desired edges, but this is also absurd.

This seems very simple but nothing related has come up in my searches.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> to make "loop cuts." Hover over one of the horizontal edges and you'll see a purple preview of the cuts. Scroll up with the mouse wheel (or press the up arrow) to increase the number of cuts. Scroll down with the mouse wheel (or press the down arrow) to decrease the number of cuts. Left-click or press <kbd>enter</kbd> to confirm the cuts.

"Loop cut" will normally cut as far across as it can. If you want to avoid cutting the upper poly, hide it first (select and press <kbd>h</kbd>), make the cuts, then unhide (press <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> to unhide everything).

Comment: that will cut the other face too, to avoid that hide other faces

Comment: This will give you more control than subdividing. When you subdivide, the result has to be 1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, etc cuts. With "loop cut" you can make an arbitrary number of cuts.

Comment: By trying to keep the top rectangle without subdivisions you'll be creating an ngon, which might bring you other problems down the line.

Comment: Well, subdivision does that too :-P There are only two ways it can go down. You either have an n-gon, or you have triangles. Both will produce triangles if the upper is NOT hidden. Both will produce an n-gon if it IS hidden.

Comment: You mentioned if you subdivide it has to be 1,3,7 etc. but I am able to choose any number for the divisions. I must be missing something.

Comment: Yes, you can subdivide any number of times you want. Subdividing once gives you 1 cut. Subdividing again gives you 3 cuts. Subdividing again gives you 7 cuts. Try using "Subdivide" to make 10 cuts without changing the selection and I think you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 7):

For this case I offer an alternative method using **Subdivide on selected top and bottom edges** of polygons you want to cut vertically. Sometimes it can be quicker than hiding & unhiding rest of the mesh when using loopcuts method ...
[image]

...and I think it is the only working method to quickly cut more than one polygon.

[image]

Just a tip - if you want to quickly deal with the resulted ngon, select the face and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to triangulate it.

Comment: saved my life, great method!

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to select Edge mode.

Select the two horizontal edges and choose to Subdivide under Mesh tools. Number of Cuts will dictate the vertical edges.

Comment: I had no idea where the mesh tools are so just selected the edges and hit `F3` and searched for _Subdivide_